# Other ways of customizing Unity web player

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using the free version of Unity. I saw that there's a way around custom in-game loading screens with "Application.GetStreamProgressForLevel" instead of "Application.LoadLevelAsync". 
I know you can change it in Unity Pro; is there a method of changing the screen in the free version?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/CustomizingtheUnityWebPlayerloadingscreen.html):

> "[M]odifying the loader images is only possible with Unity Pro."

Unfortunately, there's no way around it with the free version.